# A linear operator is bounded iff the image of every sequence convergent to $0$ is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $E,F$ be normed spaces and $T:E \rightarrow F$ a linear operator. Then, $T$ is bounded if and only if the image of every sequence on $E$ which converges to $0$ is bounded on $F$.

In order to prove the left-to-right direction, I suppose that it exists $\{x_n\} \subset E$ such that $x_n \rightarrow 0$ and $\{T x_n \} \subset F$ is not bounded.

Then, $\forall k \in \Bbb{N} \, \exists m_k \in \Bbb{N} : \lVert T x_{m_k} \rVert > k$ . Since $x_n \rightarrow 0$, $\forall \varepsilon >0 \, \exists n_\varepsilon \in \Bbb{N} \, \forall n \geq n_\varepsilon : \lVert x_n \rVert < \varepsilon$ .

Thus, for every $k \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $m_k \geq n_1 : k \lVert x_{m_k} \rVert < k < \lVert T x_{m_k} \rVert $, so $T$ is not bounded.

I am getting stuck proving the other direction. I think I should take a sequence convergent to $0$ and prove that its image also converges to 0. Then, since the continuous of a linear operator on a point is equivalent to its boundness, it would be finished.

This seems to be pretty easy but I am do not see how to prove it in detail, so every help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kind of overcomplicated in the first direction. It is much easier: if $x_n\to 0$ then by continuity, $T(x_n)\to 0$ as well, and a convergent sequence must be bounded.

For the converse, assume $T$ is not bounded. Then for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is some $x_n\in E$ with $||x_n||=1$ and $||T(x_n)||>n$. But now note that the sequence $y_n=\frac{x_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ tends to $0$, and $T(y_n)$ is not bounded, which contradicts the assumption.